# Sort an array of objects based on another array of objects in angular 7

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting, filter

I know it's been asked million+1 times. But i've found no help in those questions/answers.

I have 2 arrays of 2 different objects one string property is used to uniquely identify them. This would be the key to sort about, but said object prop names are not equal (accessValue, modifiedOption). But their values are!

```
 Object1: { ... accessValue, ... };

 Object2: { ..., modifiedOption, ... }; 

 array1:Object1[];

 array2:Object2[];
```

I'd like to sort array1 based on the object indencies of array2.
So all of array1 items'd be in the same order as array2.

These two arrays are used to model a connected dropdown selection system, which can be added to are removed from. The Addition is screwing me over (lastly added item is appended to the first place and not the last) probably because of filter below?

What I use to add new dropdowns:

```
 addFieldRow() {
    this.fieldRows.push(0); // since desired selection is not known yet but need to populate the array that represents the 1st selection so a 2nd main selection dropdown will appear on screen
  ...
  }

  public onSelect() {
     // if a selection is happened check the values of editOptions (contains data about all main selectable options) 
    this.fieldRows = this.editOptions.filter(
      option => this.selectedOptions.some(el => el.modifiedOption === option.accessValue)
    );
    this.disableSelected(); // disable already selected items (not related to my issue)
    this.optionSelected = true; // this is just for button disabled toggle
  }
```

So either i need to figure out my addRow logic (if it has any flaws) or implement a sorting utility to make sure that the objects of fieldRows are in the same order as selectedOptions' -> since this models the selection directly.

I cannot really add a stackblitz since it's hard to model my current state.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am a complete idiot!
Since I know the current index (since i am looping through fieldRows).

All I had to do is replace this:

```
public onSelect() {

    this.fieldRows = this.editOptions.filter(
      option => this.selectedOptions.some(el => el.modifiedOption === option.accessValue)
    );
```

With this:

```
  public onSelect(index) {

    this.fieldRows[index] = this.editOptions.find(option => this.selectedOptions[index].modifiedOption === option.accessValue);
    this.disableSelected();
    this.optionSelected = true;
  }
```

Now it works correctly.